# How to play Minecraft PS4 edition after updating to Bedrock edition?

Tags: ps4, minecraft-legacy-console, minecraft-bedrock-edition

We bought PS4 & Minecraft (physical disc) a while ago.  Pretty soon Minecraft got an update to Bedrock edition. However, the kids would prefer to play the old PS4 edition -> is there way to access the PS4 edition after upgrade?

**Revert approach:** We were able to revert to PS4 edition by deleting Minecraft, removing network access and installing Minecraft again from the physical disc. However, this setup is quite fragile.

**Accessing PS4 Edition from Bedrock edition:** Kids told that their friends have been able to play PS4 edition from Bedrock edition. From https://minecraft.wiki/w/PlayStation_4_Edition I found

> PlayStation 4 Edition is a separate game from Bedrock Edition and is still playable for anyone who owns it by selecting the "Editions" button on the title screen of Bedrock Edition.

However, I haven't found "Editions" button on the title screen?

Comment: https://bugs.mojang.com/browse/MCPE-60691 has some discussion. At least if bought digitally after December 10 there would be only Bedrock edition. But we have physical PS4 edition disc (and are able to revert to it as discussed above)

Answer (score 1):

- For the PS4 Edition (Yay servers and realms now.), at the bottom right I believe of the screen, there is an "Editions" button that allows you to go to the PS4 Edition (and, as a result, access the Mini Games).
- For the legacy Xbox One edition, (if you have it) it is a separate game.
- For PE and Windows 10, the versions before Bedrock resemble current Bedrock Edition.
- I do not know about Nintendo Switch Edition, but for pre-PS4/Xbox One generation consoles, there is no bedrock edition.
- I do not know about next gen consoles (PS5, etc.), as I do not own one yet, so I do not know if they have backwards compatibility for Legacy Console edition. (i.e. if PS5 will support PS4 Edition) However, it is possible that this is not true, as it wasn't true with previous generations.

Comment: PE and Windows 10 were not always BE

Comment: oops... Fixed it